# Программно разместить RadioButton в groupBox. c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Требуется разместить несколько GroupBox и в них RadioButton, чтобы потом можно было к ним обращаться.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
    {
        GroupBox myGroupBox = new GroupBox();
        myGroupBox.Location = new Point(70, 140 + (i * 50));
        myGroupBox.Size = new Size(1000, 50);
        myGroupBox.Name = "groupbox" + Convert.ToString(i);
        this.Controls.Add(myGroupBox);

        RadioButton rdo = new RadioButton();
        rdo.Name = "rbo";
        rdo.Text = "Name";
        rdo.Location = new Point(390, 20);  
    }
```

Как это реализовать, чтобы потом по i можно было обращаться(проверять состояние RadioButton?

Comment: Они все должны быть одинаковыми? Ну и одинокий `RadioButton` не имеет смысла. Либо я не понимаю, а вы не описали, желаемое поведение этих `RadioButton`-ов.

Comment: Попробуйте описать для чего это нужно, возможно вы изначально неправильно подходите к решению задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю так вам подойдет:

```
foreach (GroupBox gb in myGroupBox.Children)
{
    if (qe is RadioButton)
        {
                var litem = qe as RadioButton;
                if (litem.IsChecked())
                ...
}
```

Но для RadioButton можно использовать ListBoxEdit в котором выставить StyleSettings как RadioListBoxEditStyleSettings. Он предназначен для того чтобы хранить радиокнопки.

Comment: Не путайте WPF и WinForms.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а что в winforms нельзя обратится так к дочерним элементам?

Comment: Свойства `Children` нет (вместо него `Controls`). И `StyleSettings` тоже нет.